# c# .net grid app search page

Tags: c#, .net, search, windows-store-apps

Trying to use the guide from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh868180.aspx

My app contains Personal trainers, and personal trainers have their customers.
I want to be able to search for customers.

This is how far I am: I can search for customers on first/lastname and it will say how many results there are, IE results(3), but it will not show them.

I've included my data:

```
using PersonalTrainerGridApp.Data;
```

The `if` statement in `navigationHelper_LoadState` is confusing me, I'm not sure what to have in it, and I'm not sure if the `Filter_Checked` is correct.

Anyone have some pointers? thanks for formatting!

```
private async void navigationHelper_LoadState(object sender, LoadStateEventArgs e)
    {
        var queryText = e.NavigationParameter as String;
        // Initialize the results list.
        AllResultsCollection = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<SampleDataSource>>();

        // Keep track of the number of matching items. 
        var totalMatchingItems = 0;
        var filterList = new List<Filter>();
        var groups = await SampleDataSource.GetPersonalTrainerAsync();

        foreach (var group in groups)
        {
            var matchingItems = group.Customers.Where(
                item => 
                    item.FirstName.IndexOf(
                        queryText, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) > -1 || item.LastName.IndexOf(
                        queryText, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) > -1 );

            int numberOfMatchingItems = matchingItems.Count();
            totalMatchingItems += numberOfMatchingItems;
            if (numberOfMatchingItems > 0)
            {
                AllResultsCollection.Add(group.Customers, matchingItems);
                filterList.Add(new Filter(group.Customers, numberOfMatchingItems));
            }

        }

        // Create an entry for "All" for viewing all search results. 
        filterList.Insert(0, new Filter("All", totalMatchingItems, true));

        // Communicate results through the view model
        this.DefaultViewModel["QueryText"] = '\"' + queryText + '\"';
        this.DefaultViewModel["Filters"] = filterList;
        this.DefaultViewModel["ShowFilters"] = true;

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Invoked when a filter is selected using a RadioButton when not snapped.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The selected RadioButton instance.</param>
    /// <param name="e">Event data describing how the RadioButton was selected.</param>
    void Filter_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Retrieve the data context of the sender (the selected radio button).
        // This gives us the selected Filter object. 
        var filter = (sender as FrameworkElement).DataContext as Filter;

        // Mirror the change into the CollectionViewSource.
        // This is most likely not needed.
        if (filtersViewSource.View != null)
        {
            filtersViewSource.View.MoveCurrentTo(filter);
        }

        // Determine which filter was selected
        if (filter != null)
        {
            // Mirror the results into the corresponding Filter object to allow the
            // RadioButton representation used when not snapped to reflect the change
            filter.Active = true;

            // TODO: Respond to the change in active filter by setting this.DefaultViewModel["Results"]
            //       to a collection of items with bindable Image, Title, Subtitle, and Description properties

            if (filter.Name.Equals("All"))
            {
                var tempResults = new List<SampleDataSource>();

                // Add the items from each group to the temporary results
                // list. 
                foreach (var group in AllResultsCollection)
                {
                    tempResults.AddRange(group.Value);

                }

                // Display the items.
                this.DefaultViewModel["Results"] = tempResults;
            }
            else if (AllResultsCollection.ContainsKey(filter.Name))
            {
                this.DefaultViewModel["Results"] =
                  new List<SampleDataSource>(AllResultsCollection[filter.Name]);
            }

            // Ensure results are found
            object results;
            ICollection resultsCollection;
            if (this.DefaultViewModel.TryGetValue("Results", out results) &&
                (resultsCollection = results as ICollection) != null &&
                resultsCollection.Count != 0)
            {
                VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "ResultsFound", true);
                return;
            }
        }

        // Display informational text when there are no search results.
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "NoResultsFound", true);
    }
```

Thanks in advance, much appreciated :-)

Comment: Still trying to figure this one out, anyone out there familiar with searchpage? :)

Comment: `if(numberOfMatchingItems > 0)
                {
                    AllResultsCollection.Add(group.Customers, matchingItems);
                    filterList.Add(new Filter(group.Customers, numberOfMatchingItems));
                }`


This one is still failing, "The best overloaded method match --- has some invalid arguments